# How to convert Oracle data to JSON and then use in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

**Environment is**: Oracle APEX v4.2.2 / DB is Oracle 11gR2 / Browser is: IE11

I'm currently working on an application using Oracle APEX v4.2.2 where I need to take data within a table, convert it to JSON. I then need take this JSON data and use it within JavaScript, within one of my pages, which I will use to produce an SVG diagram.

Based on the above, how might I best tackle the above requirement, within Oracle APEX, i.e.:

1) Best tool/means to convert Oracle table data based on a certain SQL criteria to JSON?

2) How to then use this JSON data within an APEX page, to be used within a JavaScript function?

I guess my main areas that I am not sure of is how to convert this table data to JSON and then how to pass this JSON data to a JavaScript function.

Comment: Try breaking this problem down and ask separate questions for each.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Best tool/means to convert Oracle table data based on a certain SQL
>   criteria to JSON?

Assuming you are familiar with JSON concepts (e.g., objects, list, ... etc); this [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) library is fairly comprehensive to convert from SQL to JSON and vice versa.

In one of the cases I worked on, I only needed the library to convert from JSON to SQL table. For converting SQL to JSON (to send SQL table to MongoDB (JSON)), a simple cursor worked for me:

```
FOR i IN (SELECT COL1, COL2,... COLn FROM tab)
LOOP
content := '{"COL1":"'||COL1||'", "COL2":"'||COL2||'", .... "COLN":"'||COLN||'"}';
//do something
END LOOP;
```

You can concatenate the entire table into one list `[{..}, {...}, ... {..}]` and store in CLOB column

> 2) How to then use this JSON data within an APEX page, to be used
>   within a javascript function.

So the JSON collectoin is stored in your SQL table column of the type CLOB now. You can pass the value of that column into a javaScript variable.

```
var text = $v(clob_col);
```

But since it is stored as text, you need to convert it to an object using the syntax

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

More on that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Best tool/means to convert Oracle table data based on a certain SQL
>   criteria to JSON?

did you try to use RESTful Web Service in Application Express 4.2, by using it you can create a small web service which generates json outputs based on pl/sql or sql. then you can consume it by javascript in your app or other apps.
please check the official oracle documentation
"Creating and Using a RESTful Web Service in Application Express 4.2"

> 2) How to then use this JSON data within an APEX page, to be used
>   within a javascript function

by using a code similar to below you can consume that web service for using data within your app

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt or http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```